# Syntax error in styles class React

Tags: reactjs

I'm getting a syntax error when trying to create a variable for a component style. I've read the documentation over and over and the syntax looks fine...am I missing something?

Syntax error: Unexpected token (8:14)

```
 const heroStyle = {
  height: 100%,
  backgroundImage: "url('+ imgUrl +')",
  backgroundSize: 'cover',
  overflow: 'hidden',
   }

<header className="masthead" style={ heroStyle }>
```

Comment: Try height: "100%"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`height: '100%',`

and I don't think this will work `backgroundImage: "url('+ imgUrl +')"`,

Should be able to use template literals? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals

Comment: Thanks! It did work like this though, no need for literals (I think it's cause I'm not using Babel?)

Answer (score 0):

```
height: 100%
```

should be

```
height: '100%'
```

Comment: I literally just saw it as I loaded your answer. Thanks a lot!